# php validation using cURL

Tags: php, curl

im trying to validate a form using php because it has a file input in it that requires validation.

basically, the action of my form sends it to validate.php, which validates the form fields and either sends the invalid data back to the form using POST in cURL:

```
$data = array(
    'nameError' => $nameError,
    'name' => $name,
    'description' => $desc,
    'descError' => $descError,
    'spriceError' => $spriceError,
    'sprice' => $sprice,
    'iprice' => $iprice,
    'incprice' => $incprice,
    'incprice' => $incprice,
    'durError' => $durError,
    'location' => $location,
    'img' => $imgError
);

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $field_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';

}
rtrim($field_string, '&');


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sellanitem.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
header("Location: sellanitem.php");
```

in my form page, i check to see if the post data is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];

}else{
    $name = "";
}

if(isset($_POST['nameError'])){
    $nameError = $_POST['nameError'];
}else{
    $nameError = "";
}

if(isset($_POST['durError'])){
    $durError = $_POST['durError'];

}else{
    $durError = "";
}

if(isset($_POST['description'])){
    $desc = $_POST['description'];

}else{
    $desc = "";
}
```

etc.

then i display messages based on the values of the variable:

```
            <td>
                <textarea id="name" name="name" title="name" rows="2" cols ="60" style="resize:none; float:right; font-family: Arial;" value=""><?php echo $name;?></textarea>
<?php
if($nameError != ""){
    echo $nameError;
}
```

i came to this method after looking up "submit form automatically php" in google. my thought was that if i could automatically submit a form i could simply include the error messages as data fields with an action back to my sellanitem.php. i dont know thought, this cURL stuff is confusing to me, so far i submit the form fields with invalid inputs to test it and it simply loads a blank page. i also tried putting header("location: sellanitem.php") but the error messages arent displayed.

suggestions of what might be wrong / alternate methods that would achieve the same result?

cheers, 
bundy

Comment: You could pass the parameter array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` opt, and it would escape parameters properly (you currently missing that).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse the return from the cURL request you need:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

in addition to

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

However, it appears that's a local file... Why can't you just `include 'sellanitem.php'` rather than passing the post data through cURL?

Also worth noting a `Location` header should use an [`Absolute URI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Examples_of_absolute_URIs)

Comment: i want to validate the form after submitting it. would include('sellanitem.php') do that?

Comment: If you're submitting to `validate.php` you can include `sellanitem.php` after to post it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting up an output buffer so you need to assign the exec to a variable:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Data is what it returns.  If you send back an json string of errors, etc, you're golden.

Comment: it still loads a blank page. do i need to include a header back to the page the  curl_exec?

Comment: If you're redirecting, you're just going to that page. From your code, nothing is being brought over to the page.

Comment: whats the significance of the output buffer. if i want the post data sent back to the page with curl do i simply use $_POST['name'] etc?

Comment: I only mentioned that so you can get back the result, since you weren't assigning it to a variable.  Just a crude way to get info back, in this case.  Disregard it.